# Is it possible to change the value of va_arg?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I want to do a function in which the arguments are a vector and multiple arguments. And then i assign the values of the vector to those multiple arguments one by one.

The code i have below is not correct because you can't do this with a macro **va_arg(ap, int*) = vector[i];**.

So i wanted to know if there was a way to change the value of the multiple values.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void assign_values(int* vector, int *n_args, ...)
{
   register int i;
   va_list ap;

   va_start(ap, n_args);


   for(i = 0; i<*n_args; i++)
   {
       va_arg(ap, int*) = vector[i];
   }

   va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
   int vector[3];
   int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
   vector[0] = 3;
   vector[1] = 1;
   vector[2] = 2;
   assign_values(vector, &a, &b, &c);

   printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);

   return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't you mean `*va_arg(ap, int*) = vector[i];`? That would be perfectly legal.

Comment: Why? Why you want to use a method, variable arguments, created to assign multiple and variable argument number in the call, to change the passed values with values of an array passed with it??

Comment: voting to close this as a simple typographical error (missing `*` for pointer dereference)

Comment: I tried it that why but the output is 0 0 0.

Comment: Your `n_args` is pointer to int variable that has value 0, so the `for` loop is not  executed ever.

Comment: and also: no, it is not possible to change the value of a `va_arg` if you mean that; your code is not even trying to change the value of a `va_arg` (which is a pointer), but the value of the pointed-to variable.

Comment: @Frankie_C: C does not support _methods_. Only _functions.

Comment: So you pass pointers to the values you want to store each field of the vector to?

Comment: @Olaf Method as a synonym of "way to do it". Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but you are using the variadic argument in a wrong way. You are using the first argument (which is `&a`) as the amount of arguments but you should have a sentinel at the end. In addition you are not dereferencing the pointer to assign to it. `va_arg(ap, int*)` is not an lvalue. `*va_arg(ap, int*)` instead is assignable.

```
void assign_values(int* vector, int* args, ...)
{
   register int i;
   va_list ap;

   va_start(ap, args);

   int* arg = args;
   int index = 0;
   while (arg)
   {
     *arg = vector[index];
     arg = va_arg(ap, int*);
     ++index;
   }

   va_end(ap);
}

assign_values(vector, &a, &b, &c, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `va_arg(ap, int*)` you get a *pointer* to an `int`. Trying to change that pointer accomplishes nothing, especially since `vector[i]` is *not* a pointer.

To modify the value that a pointer points to, you need to use the dereference operator `*`. So the following might work:

```
*(va_arg(ap, int*)) = vector[i];
```

Also, you don't call the function with the correct arguments,  The variable `n_args` points to the variable `a` in the `main` function, which is *zero*. Unless you expect to modify the `n_args` argument in the function don't pass it as a pointer at all, then call the function as

```
assign_values(vector, 3, &a, &b, &c);
```