# How to assign variadic/variable arguments in C++

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, variadic

I'm trying to create a function to assign default or input values to several (scalar) parameters using variadic/variable input arguments as:

```
void set_params(const vector<double> &input, int n, ...) {  
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i < input.size()) {
      va_arg(args, int) = input[i];
    }
  }
  va_end(args);
}

int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
set_params({10, 20}, 3, a, b, c);
```

However, I'm getting the error on the assignment `va_arg(args, int) = input[i]`. Is it possible somehow to do assignment with variable arguments, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to change the value of va\_arg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531090/is-it-possible-to-change-the-value-of-va-arg)

Comment: If you want to modify the parameter in `va_arg`, you have to pass it by pointer, instead of by reference or by value. Besides, don't use variadic arguments mechanism if possible. There are many other methods to do the same thing but more friendly.

Comment: [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#F-varargs) advice _against_ the use of `va_args` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using C's `va_` stuff, C++ has it's own variadic template arguments, [which you should preferably use](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#F-varargs)

I'm no expert on this, but it could look a little bit like

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Arg>
void set_params(const std::vector<double> &input, Arg&... arg) {
    unsigned int i{0};
    (
        [&] {
            if (i < size(input)) {
                arg = input[i++];
            }
        }(), // immediately invoked lambda/closure object
        ...); // C++17 fold expression
}

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    set_params({10, 20}, a, b, c);

    std::cout
        << a << ' '
        << b << ' '
        << c << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call your lambda, just add `()` after lambda's body. After that your code works.

Comment: I'd pass on to a function with a `std::index_sequence` rather than have `i++` https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1883e288d92a8a87

Comment: This is brilliant. Maybe a little bit more of background explanation would be suitable. This uses a C++17 [_fold expression_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) with the comma operator. That way a lambda expression can be mapped over the variadic arguments.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change a variable, that is passed as function parameter, you must use a pointer or a reference. For example the following function will have no effect, since `x` is passed by value and not by reference.

```
void set_zero(int x) {
    x = 0;
}
```

In C++ you have two options to pass something by reference. Either pass a *pointer* or pass a *lvalue reference*:

```
void set_zero(int *x) {
    *x = 0;
}

void set_zero(int &x) {
    x = 0;
}
```

Both of these will change the original variable to zero. I haven't found a way of passing a lvalue reference though a variadic function call, so I suggest you use pointers. In your case the code would look like

```
void set_params(const vector<double> &input, int n, ...) {  
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i < input.size()) {
            va_arg(args, int*) = input[i];
        }
    }
    va_end(args);
}

int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
set_params({10, 20}, 3, &a, &b, &c);
```

That beeing set, variadic arguments are a very unsafe way of passing variables. In your example, if someone changes the type of `a`, `b`, and `c` to another type, you will run into serious problems, as the type used in the `set_params` function no longer matches the type of the variables passed. You could do the whole function in a more safe way by e.g. using a vector also for the pointers.

```
template<typename T>
void set_params(const vector<T> &input, const vector<T*> &variables) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < variables.size(); i++ ) {
        if ( i < input.size() ) {
            *variables[i] = input[i];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
set_params<int>({10,20}, {&a, &b, &c});
```